# How can I add HTML comments with an URL to an XML file?

Tags: html, xml, docusignconnect

I'm working with DocuSign on some email templates that are included on an XML file...

My issue is that I'm trying to add this snippet to that XML, I already substituted the "&" for "&" on the url, but, since the template is supposed to work an look good on most email domains, I need to add HTML comments when it's opened on Outlook desktop (The url won't work, I changed it for security reasons)

```
<td>
  <!--[if mso]>
  <table width="50%">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://www.page.com/en-ca"><img width="620" src="https://page--page.page.page.page.com/page/page.ImageServer?id=0000A0000056se5&amp;oid=00E8E000000F7CG&amp;lastMod=1005000662000" style="text-align: right; width: 207px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;"></a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div style="display:none">
    <![endif]-->
    <a href="https://www.page.com/en-ca"><img class="header-image" alt="Omnipod Header" src="https://page--page.page.page.page.com/page/page.ImageServer?id=0000A0000056se5&amp;oid=00E8E000000F7CG&amp;lastMod=1005000662000"></img></a>
    <!--[if mso]>
  </div>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
```

When I try to add this specific comment, I receive an error saying that the syntaxis is not correct, I was able to isolate the issue, the issue is just on the URL on the comment, when I delete and save, no warning pops up. The idea is the header shows up instead of the one that's not in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after several tries, the solution is to not put two dashes, one dash has to be changed:

'--' > '& # 4 5 ; -' (If I don't leave the spaces it will apear  like this --)

With that, the url won't be affected and misread by the XML compiler